# Using amplifier to drive an electromagnet

Tags: amplifier, electromagnetism, speakers, solenoid, function-generator

my group-mate and I are currently trying to create a kind of a simple speaker which could vibrate up to 1 kHz. The speaker we designed was simply made up of small solenoid and a cylindrical magnet, we are using a function generator to generate the signal. However we noticed that the vibration can only be seen up to 400 Hz only (bigger vibrations at lower frequency and decreases as the frequency increases).

We believe because the output impedance of the functional generator is 50 ohm, the voltage it gives onto our solenoid is also relatively low and hence the magnetic field is also not so strong.
If we could amplify the current that passes through the solenoid, we believe that we could see more vibration.
However, we are not sure on what kind of amplifier should we use, as too high of an amplifier may easily cause heating up on the wire.

Our current solenoid has a resistance of 2.65 kilo ohm, with radius of 5.5 mm and it is about 2000-3000 turns.

Comment: Audio amplifier perhaps with a current limiting resistor.

Comment: Is there any specific current limit we need to find out? If yes, what formula would we find this?

Answer (score 0):

> We believe because the output impedance of the functional generator is
>   50 ohm, the voltage it gives onto our solenoid is also relatively low
>   and hence the magnetic field is also not so strong.

If the DC resistance of your coil is 2.65 kohm then a paltry 50 ohms in the signal generator isn't going to add any appreciable depreciation of the signal.

It is quite likely that the inductance of your coil is quite high and it is this that makes the current consumption so low as the frequency rises. To combat this you need voltage but, because of the large self-inductance of the coil you will hit other problems associated with back-emfs potentially destroying your amplifier hence, I can't recommend an op-amp solution.

Why don't you get hold of an old loudspeaker and count how many turns it has and re-adjust your design to be more in-line with what genuine speaker manufacturers use. In other words, I believe you have too many turns, possibly ten times too many.

I also think that your resistance measurement of 2.65 kohm is too many - have you tried estimating the wire length and using an on-line calculator to give you an estimate of DC resistance for the gauge of copper you are using?

Comment: I see, okay thank you for making us understand more about what we are facing.
What about an audio amplifier instead of an op amp? Do you think it would work?

Well, we actually bought our solenoid online. They only gave us the following information: power 2.4 Watts and wire dimension of 12 x 28. We found out the DC resistance using a multimeter and yeah, we did think it was really high too.
Maybe we will have to open up and remove some turns from our solenoid.

Answer (score 0):

You have some unknowns in your situation that can be hard to guess.  Some can be measured with a suitable circuit configuration.  If you have the full specifications of your solenoid and your function generator it also improves the quality of the answers you may receive.

You mention a limit of 2.4W for your solenoid. This is likely due to heat dissapation or wire current capacity.  This will be reached with DC around 80V at a current of 30mA.

With AC signals the impedance will be higher than the DC resistance and increase with frequency requiring even more voltage to reach the maximum allowed power.

So you will not be stressing the solenoid until you drive it with 80V DC or even higher voltages using AC.  The amount of voltage allowed will differ at each frequency and cannot be predicted without knowing the impedance characteristics of the solenoid.

When driving the solenoid in a circuit with a series resistor you can measure the voltage across the solenoid and the series resistor (to calculate the current) and use this to determine the impedance at your selected frequencies.  Using this information you can calculate the maximum allowed drive voltage at each frequency of interest.

An (Hi-Fi) audio amplifier is your best choice as these are cheap and the voltages are close to what you need.  A 500W amplifier rated to drive a 16Ohm speaker should have a 90V compliance and would probably be able to do justice to your solenoid.  The amplifier will not be working hard at all but you need the high power rating to get the high voltage drive from a consumer (low impedance) speaker driver.  If you had a better matched amplifier you would only need it to be rated at about 5W at 50mA with a source resistance under 2kOhms and a 80+ Volt compliance.

Also note that the machnetic field characteristics are dependant on the type and size of core thatyou have.  If it is a simple solid iron core you may experience heading due to eddy current losses and less magnetic field than expected.

If you indicate your project details a bit more you may find that there are much better ways to achieve what you want to do.  Generally these days lower voltages and higher currents are preferred expecially if all you need is 2.4W of solenoid drive.